# Cordova plugin Network Information Warning: will always evaluate to 'true' after bug fixing

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm having this issue on xcode when I build the app:

/MY_APP/.../Plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/CDVConnection.m:121:10: Address of 'UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification' will always evaluate to 'true'
/MY_APP/.../Plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/CDVConnection.m:121:58: Address of 'UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification' will always evaluate to 'true'

I was reading: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9702 a bug fixed 5 days ago but my app was created today from scratch.

I added the plugin as usual:

```
$ cordova plugin add  cordova-plugin-network-information
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for ios
$
```

I'm using Node 4.2, cordova 5.3 and XCode 7.0

This is the code:

```
if (&UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification && &UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onPause) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onResume) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: fixed means it's been fixed on the developer branch, but it take a while until the new plugin version is released. You can install it from the pull request that fixed the issue or see the changes and apply them to your plugin (https://github.com/pstoll/cordova-plugin-network-information). Anyway, those are just warnings, your app won't break

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile
The app works fine, but I don't know if Apple could be reject it by this warning....